# Hype game or be modest in game dev tycoon?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

What should you pick when a interviewer ask you a question that you can reply either "be modest" or "hype game!" to?

Does it have big influence on your game scores?

Comment: Hyping it increases the hype value, but if the game doesn't live up to the expectations you take a big hit in sales. I think.

Answer (score 5):

What Shadur left in comments is correct.  If you are expecting high results on your reviews after development, especially if the game has the chance to be a hit, you want to hype it.  It will result in increased marketing and sales/units sold.  If your end product gets bad reviews and overall isn't that good you will take a large decrease in sales and your fan-base could decrease by more than average.

I highly recommend goolging the wiki for (can't on this pc [work filters]) and looking into what makes a great game or what causes x and y... ETC.

The best thing to think of when you encounter this is it is a risk/return multiplier.  Good turns really good and bad turns really bad.

Also, when you "be modest" and in turn develop a hit game it will not hurt you.  You will get a message about it, but no negative impacts occur.

Comment: Even if you're modest, it will still give you a small Hype boost (about 5?).

Comment: @PaulMarshall: There are default some factors to hype. If you make a sequel, it will also get a few hype points to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you "Be modest" then nothing happens.

If you "Hype game!" then sales will be adjusted.  If the review score is lower than 5, then "Hype game" reduces sales.  If the review score is higher than 5 then "Hype game" increases sales.

Review score is not affected by "Hype game!" or by hype (as from marketing).

Comment: 5 does not seem to be the magic number.  I just lost sales and I had an average score of 6.5

Comment: @miR I looked at the code and it said 5.

Comment: Perhaps it's been updated then. I can guarantee this isn't the case as of yesterday.